# Flash builder cannot verify whether the AIR application ID matches the pattern specified in the provisioning profile

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flash-builder, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to build an iOS app in Flash Builder, and I keep seeing this warning:

"Flash builder cannot verify whether the AIR application ID matches the pattern specified in the provisioning profile. If they do not match, the application package may not be installable on a device"

The app ID in the application.xml matches the app ID set up in the provisioning profile. It builds the IPA, but when I install in iTunes, it refuses to install the app and says "the entitlements are invalid"

It sounds like mismatched app IDs, but I've verified that they do match. I've Googled it and can't seem to find any reference to this particular message. My next best guess is that maybe Flash builder is having difficulty reading the mobileprovision file.

Answer (score 3):

Flash Builder 4.7 beta 2.

We just had this problem today.

This occurred if we were offline (no internet connection).

It appears from a "Charles" http request monitoring session that the flashbuilder is trying to reach an Apple DTD document to verify a yourAppName-info.pList file.

So the solution.... connect to the internet when doing a distribution release build.